# how to pass data to two different nodes exact same

Tags: ros, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I  am working on a project to command six motors around same time. Due to my project requirement, I have created two different nodes to command 3 motors on each node. But, I am wondering how can I pass command information to these nodes at exact same time. So that, two nodes will start executing the commands at same time. I really appreciate it if anyone can help me with this issue. Thanking and have a nice day.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400551/how-to-pass-data-to-two-different-nodes-exact-same/) by [rcbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/80739/rcbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2022-05-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you could use `message_filters` package?

http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters

> ###Overview
>
> `message_filters` is a utility library
> for use with roscpp and rospy. It
> collects commonly used message
> "filtering" algorithms into a common
> space. A message filter is defined as
> something which a message arrives into
> and may or may not be spit back out of
> at a later point in time.
>
> An example is the time synchronizer,
> which takes in messages of different
> types from multiple sources, and
> outputs them only if it has received a
> message on each of those sources with
> the same timestamp.

This will allow you to get the output at the same time, but I'm not sure about the execution start time in these nodes...

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rcbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/80739/rcbot/) on 2022-05-15**:
Thank you ljaniec for the answer. I had a look in to this message_filters before.But, whatever I understand it wont serve my purpose. May be I am wrong and will double check again.Once again thank you so much :)